# Foundation 6.2.4 modal

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I try to implement a modal with foundation 6.2.4, but it's not working :s

The modal is hide, but i can't display it.

The code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RIA2-Projet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
    <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
    <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
    <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
    <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<p><a data-open="exampleModal1">Click me for a modal</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit :
If in my app.js file i put :

```
$(document).foundation();
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var popup = new Foundation.Reveal($('#exampleModal1'));
});
```

It's work, but it suppose to be working without it right?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the features / plugins of Foundation require initialisation to work: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing

Your code is fine, but the `$(document).foundation();` is required to run any of the Foundation plugins that use JavaScript / jQuery.

You could also initialise just the modals with:

`$('reveal').foundation();`

Here is a fiddle with it working (using the minimum file includes): https://jsfiddle.net/gbyobLt5/